# A simple file handling code at C stuck at do/while loop

Tags: c, while-loop

```
int main(void) {
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    FILE *in;

    struct sigrecord {
        int signum;
        char signame[10];
        char sigdesc[100];
    } sigrec;
    if ((in = fopen("signals.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        fputs("Cannot open signals.txt file\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    do {
        int n = fscanf(in, "%d%9s%*[ \t]%99[^\n]", &sigrec.signum,
                       sigrec.signame, sigrec.sigdesc);
        if (n == 3) {
            printf("Signal\n number = %d\n name = %s\n description = %s\n\n",
                   sigrec.signum, sigrec.signame, sigrec.sigdesc);
        } else if (n != EOF) {
            fputs("Failed to match signum, signame or sigdesc\n", stderr);
            status = EXIT_FAILURE;
            break;
        }
    } while (1);
    if (fclose(in) == EOF) {
        fputs("Failed to close file\n", stderr);
        status = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Output is fine, but while(1) loop does not end do{} loop and my program gets stuck after doing its purpose, printing output perfectly. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What happens if you add an `else if (n == EOF) { break; }`?

Comment: You want want this loop to break either when an input error is received OR EOF is encountered. Example: if you had perfect input you could pull your three members correctly. Now suppose there is no more input. The next scan attempt will return EOF, which will test false against *both* `(n != EOF)` and `(n == 3)`. Therefore, the loop never breaks. You need to break on EOF no matter what.

Comment: Instead of `do/while`, just use `while( fscanf(...) == 3 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `break` if `scanf` was not successful despite the reason.

```
} 
else {
    if (n != EOF) {
        fputs("Failed to match signum, signame or sigdesc\n", stderr);
        status = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    break;
}
```